# Why does ECS CloudFormation template create an EC2 Spot Fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I created a cluster in ECS with basic settings, nothing specific about the configuration except that I am using 1 On Demand t2.micro EC2 instance for the cluster.

I wanted to see what exactly was created and took a look at the [CloudFormation template](https://gist.github.com/pahud/399f0931c68a9137f8d1113ed8c0d942) the cluster created.

I noticed in the template it has a configuration for EcsSpotFleet

```
EcsSpotFleet:
    Condition: CreateWithSpot
    Type: AWS::EC2::SpotFleet
    Properties:
      SpotFleetRequestConfigData:
        AllocationStrategy: !Ref SpotAllocationStrategy
        IamFleetRole: !Ref IamSpotFleetRoleArn
        TargetCapacity: !Ref AsgMaxSize
        SpotPrice: !If [ CreateWithSpotPrice, !Ref SpotPrice, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue' ]
        TerminateInstancesWithExpiration: true
        LaunchSpecifications: 
....
```

**I am wondering why is this created?** Because I know the Cluster instances are created with ASG + LC. My only explanation is this fleet is used for running the CloudFormation stack. I cannot find an explanation to this in the documentation, not even sure if instances are needed for CloudFormation stack run.

p.s. I am very new to AWS, also have very little knowledge on CloudFormation.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. It creates spot fleet because you define it `AWS::EC2::SpotFleet`.

Comment: This template was used for ECS cluster creation. I have not written this template. I used the console to configure an ECS cluster.

Comment: this part might be used for Fargate and not applicable to your situation. not all code in CloudFormation will be executed. it still depends on the "Condition" flag

Comment: Yes, Thank you! That is exactly correct, it depends on the UseSpot flag, and this is passed as false in my configuration. Can you form it as an answer so I can upvote and mark as answered?

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Fargate and EC2 are two completely separate compute services. An EC2 spot fleet would not be related to Fargate in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all code in CloudFormation will be executed. It still depends on the "Condition" flag.

AWS usually create a template that covers most of the user cases and enables/disable parts of the template using the "Condition"

You can read more about Condition in AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html